# Moving HTML tags/elements automatically with text editor

Tags: html, regex, replace, automation, notepad++

I have about 1500 html files, and all of them have an html `<audio>` tag inside the `<main>` tag, generally found near the beginning of the `<main>` tag.

We need to move all these `<audio>` tags to right before the closing `</main>` tag.

Since we are talking about 1500 html files, is there a way to automate this task?

for clarity, we have pages like this:

```
    <main>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <audio src="someaudio.mp3"></audio>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </main>
```

and want to fix them to this:

```
    <main>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <audio src="someaudio.mp3"></audio>
    </main>
```

Each audio tag is custom to each page.

Each page is different.

I use notepad++ usually, I'm working on a windows environment.

No javascript. This must be done to the html file directly.

EDIT: Edited for clarity, sorry about that.

Comment: This question isn't very clear. What exactly do you need to do. what tag? where? and you want to "move all this tags to before"? what does that mean?

Comment: It might be confusing because you mix up the words "tag" and "element", which are two different things. You can't have a tag inside another tag.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not using correctly the terms. Do the examples help? I'm afraid to to edit and make everything more confusing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is *sort of* achievable, but I can see many pitfalls.

1500 files is a *lot* of files, so I can see why you want to automate. However, at the end of this you're still going to need to verify each one has worked out how you expected because, as you say:

> Each audio tag is custom to each page.
>
> Each page is different.

Anyway, onto a "solution" that'll get you closer to what you need.

This is what I had some success with:

[image: My Find/Replace settings]

Breaking it down...

### The Find.

```
<main(.*)(<audio.*?</audio>)(.*)</main>
```

- `<main(.*)`
  This is finding a `<main>` tag followed by any content including newlines as we have the `matches newline` option selected. We're holding onto the content in a group (denoted by the brackets) as we'll need it later in the replace.
- `(<audio.*?</audio>)`
  This is finding and holding onto the full `<audio>` tag.
- `(.*)</main>`
  This is finding any content after the `<audio>` tag, but before the closing `</main>` tag, and holding onto it.

### The Replace.

```
<main$1$3$2\r\n</main>
```

- `<main$1`
  we need to put back the opening `<main>` tag because we didn't capture it. The $1 contains the first lot of content we captured, so we put that back in now.
- `$3`
  now we put back any content we found after the `<audio>` tag that we captured in the 3rd group.
- `$2\r\n<main>`
  now we put back the audio tag itself, a new line and the closing `</main>` tag.

### Caveats.

The above is based on your simple examples. This is not "real world" HTML.

Over 1500 HTML files I doubt very much that this will work for every single one. Some will be structured in an odd way that prevents it doing exactly what you want.

Comment: That worked on most of the files I checked. Since the original code was created by an HTML5 code editor it was standard enough.